# GHCi Debugger not hitting breakpoints recursively: Why, and what's the solution?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a simple recursive program that doesn't quite work. So I'm trying to use the ghci debugger to figure out what's going on. I set breakpoints on all lines of functions `recurse`, `progress` and `shaded`, and it catches the first few. But when I get to the second line of `progress`, every invocation of :continue drops me back on that same line of code, even though I'm calling `recurse` and `shaded` from there and expecting my breakpoints to work. Here's the code:

```
import System.Environment

type Pos = (Int,Int) 
type Acc = ([[Pos]], [Pos])

main = do
  getArgs >>= putStrLn . show . length . combos . read . head

combos n = recurse n [] (allPos n) []

recurse :: Int -> [[Pos]] -> [Pos] -> [Pos] -> [[Pos]]
recurse n done avail inProg
   | length inProg == n = inProg:done
   | null avail = done
   | otherwise = fst $ foldr (progress n inProg) (done,avail) avail

progress :: Int -> [Pos] -> Pos -> Acc -> Acc
progress n inProg pos (done, avail)  =
  (recurse n done (filter (not . shaded pos) remain) (pos:inProg), remain)
  where remain = tail avail

allPos n =  [ (i,j) | i <- [0..n-1], j <- [0..n-1] ]

shaded :: Pos -> Pos -> Bool
shaded (i,j) (k,l) =
  k == i
  || l == j
  || k+l == i+j
  || k-l == i-j
  || abs (k-i) < 3 && abs (l-j) < 3
```

Why will the ghci debugger not stop on breakpoints in functions called by `progress`? Is there something like "non-reentrancy" turning them off? How can I get the debugger to break on every recursive call to these functions?

GHCi version 7.8.4

**Update:** I suspect this may have something to do with cached results, but it's not obvious to me that these functions have been called with the same arguments twice. Could be a bug in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is working as expected, but you have to take into account lazy evaluation.

If you break at the guard lines in `recurse` (lines 13 -- 15) and the call to recurse in progress (line 19) you'll see this pattern when the program is run with `:main 2`:

```
Stopped at prog0.hs:13:6-23   - recurse
Stopped at prog0.hs:14:6-15   - recurse
Stopped at prog0.hs:15:18-67  - recurse, call to foldr progress
Stopped at prog0.hs:19:3-74   - in progress, pos = (1,1)
Stopped at prog0.hs:19:3-74   - in progress, pos = (1,0)
Stopped at prog0.hs:19:3-74   - in progress, pos = (0,1)
Stopped at prog0.hs:19:3-74   - in progress, pos = (0,0)
Stopped at prog0.hs:13:6-23   - in recurse
Stopped at prog0.hs:14:6-15
Stopped at prog0.hs:13:6-23   - in recurse
Stopped at prog0.hs:14:6-15   
Stopped at prog0.hs:13:6-23   - in recurse
Stopped at prog0.hs:14:6-15  
Stopped at prog0.hs:13:6-23   - in recurse
Stopped at prog0.hs:14:6-15
```

However, if you change `progress` to force its result:

```
import Control.DeepSeq

progress n inProg pos (done, avail)  = let
  result = (recurse n done (filter (not . shaded pos) remain) (pos:inProg), remain)
  in deepseq result result
  where remain = tail avail
```

then the break point pattern is:

```
Stopped at prog1.hs:14:6-23   - recurse
Stopped at prog1.hs:15:6-15   - recurse
Stopped at prog1.hs:16:18-67  - recurse, call to foldr progress
Stopped at prog1.hs:21:6-26   - progress, pos = (1,1)
Stopped at prog1.hs:14:6-23   - recurse
Stopped at prog1.hs:15:6-15
Stopped at prog1.hs:21:6-26   - progress, pos = (1,0)
Stopped at prog1.hs:14:6-23   - recurse
Stopped at prog1.hs:15:6-15
Stopped at prog1.hs:21:6-26   - progress, pos = (0,1)
Stopped at prog1.hs:14:6-23   - recurse
Stopped at prog1.hs:15:6-15
Stopped at prog1.hs:21:6-26   - progress, pos = (0,0)
Stopped at prog1.hs:14:6-23   - recurse
Stopped at prog1.hs:15:6-15
```

The recursive calls to `recurse` are now interleaved because we are forcing them right away.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm not thrilled about making code changes to debug my code, but am thrilled to have a solution that works!

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding another answer to demonstrate how to use `Debug.Trace` to perform "printf" debugging with pure functions.

Here is `recurse` and `progress` with trace statements added to print
their call arguments. We can safely use `undefined` here because the
trace calls will always return False.

```
import System.Environment
import Debug.Trace

...

recurse :: Int -> [[Pos]] -> [Pos] -> [Pos] -> [[Pos]]
recurse n done avail inProg
   | trace msg False = undefined
   | length inProg == n = inProg:done
   | null avail = done
   | otherwise = fst $ foldr (progress n inProg) (done,avail) avail
   where msg = unwords ["recurse:", show n, show done, show avail, show inProg]

progress :: Int -> [Pos] -> Pos -> Acc -> Acc
progress n inProg pos (done, avail)
  | trace msg False = undefined
    where msg = unwords ["progress:", show n, show inProg, show pos, show (done, avail)]
progress n inProg pos (done, avail)  =
  (recurse n done (filter (not . shaded pos) remain) (pos:inProg), remain)
  where remain = tail avail

...
```

And here is the output for `:main 2`:

```
recurse: 2 [] [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)] []
progress: 2 [] (1,1) ([],[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
recurse: 2 [] [] [(1,1)]
progress: 2 [] (1,0) ([],[(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)])
recurse: 2 [] [] [(1,0)]
progress: 2 [] (0,1) ([],[(1,0),(1,1)])
recurse: 2 [] [] [(0,1)]
progress: 2 [] (0,0) ([],[(1,1)])
recurse: 2 [] [] [(0,0)]
```

In general with trace statements added evaluation proceeds in a strict fashion as printing out the function arguments will force them.

Comment: Thanks @ErikR, I remember reading about the trace function but never used it and forgot. I guess since you mention it, this is an approach preferred by many Haskellers over use of the GHCi Debugger? I tend to prefer testing my code in an unmangled form, but I am no stranger to throwing debug info to the log! Perhaps many find the user experience with GHCi Debugger a bit uneven? :)

Comment: I can't speak for others, but With Haskell I've actually never used the debugger - I've either resort to printf/trace-debugging or writing test cases.